# Returning error upon comment being flagged as spam

Tags: comments, comment-form, errors

Hello Im using a custom filter that hooks to `pre_comment_approved` to look for bad words in a custom way. Now when the comment gets flagged it returns `spam`.

How could I post back an error to the comments page so the user is aware that his/her email was sent to spam because of the use of a blacklisted word?

Thanks

```
function my_wp_blacklist_check( $approved , $commentdata ) {

$mod_keys = trim( get_option('blacklist_keys') );
if ( '' == $mod_keys )
    return false; // If moderation keys are empty
$words = explode("\n", $mod_keys );

foreach ( (array) $words as $word ) {
    $word = trim($word);
    str_pad($word, 1, STR_PAD_BOTH);
    // Skip empty lines
    if ( empty($word) ) { continue; }

    // Do some escaping magic so that '#' chars in the
    // spam words don't break things:
    $word = preg_quote($word, '#');

    $pattern = "#\b$word\b#i";
    if (preg_match($pattern, $commentdata['comment_content'])) {
        return 'spam';
    }
}
return true;
}
add_filter( 'pre_comment_approved' , 'my_wp_blacklist_check' , '99', 2 );
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I've handled passing messages back to the user before: within your current function, set a [transient](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) with your message:

```
set_transient( 'admin_notice', 'Please put down your weapon. You have 20 seconds to comply.' );
```

Then add a new hooked function:

```
function admin_notices() {
    $notice = get_transient( 'admin_notice' );
    if ( $notice ) {
        echo '<div class="error"><p>' . $notice . '</p></div>';
        delete_transient( 'admin_notice' );
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_notices', 'admin_notices' );
```